Work in Adiabatic Expansion
I was reading the Carnot Cycle, and I came across the reversible adiabatic expansion process which provide work if we maintained adiabatic conditions for a system, (its temperature gets decreases in that process) so does it mean that a system would continuously produce work and keep expanding, if it is maintained to adiabatic conditions? 
Process 2-3 is the reversible adiabatic expansion process.

Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Any expansion against external pressure provides work, it is not limited to specific isothermal nor adiabatic conditions. It expands as long as external conditions - given by the engine configuration - allow it to expand.

You may find useful reviewing search results for site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org OR site:wikipedia.org "reversible work" "adiabatic expansion"

In the Carnot Cycle, you have to stop the expansion at some point so that you can close the cycle.  Also,, the work done in the adiabatic expansion must be equal to the work received in the adiabatic compression.
